# How to mock a uuid generator which return different values for different calls?

Tags: scala, mocking, mockito, specs2

I have a uuid generator, like:

```
class NewUuid {
    def apply: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString.replace("-", "")
}
```

And other class can use it:

```
class Dialog {
    val newUuid = new NewUuid
    def newButtons(): Seq[Button] = Seq(new Button(newUuid()), new Button(newUuid()))
}
```

Now I want to test the `Dialog` and mock the `newUuid`:

```
val dialog = new Dialog {
    val newUuid = mock[NewUuid]
    newUuid.apply returns "uuid1"
}
dialog.newButtons().map(_.text) === Seq("uuid1", "uuid1")
```

You can see the returned uuid is always `uuid1`.

Is it possible to let `newUuid` to return different values for different calls? e.g. The first call returns `uuid1`, the second returns `uuid2`, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newUuid.apply returns "uudi1" thenReturns "uuid2"
```

https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.5/org.specs2.guide.UseMockito.html

Answer (score 1):

Use an iterator to produce your UUIDs

```
def newUuid() = UUID.randomUUID().toString.replace("-", "")

val defaultUuidSource = Iterator continually newUuid()

class Dialog(uuids: Iterator[String] = defaultUuidSource) {
  def newButtons() = Seq(
    Button(uuids.next()),
    Button(uuids.next())
  )
}
```

Then provide a different one for testing:

```
val testUuidSource = Iterator from 1 map {"uuid" + _}
new Dialog(testUuidSource)
```